# Is there a wordpress plugin where admin user can create users in front end?

Tags: wordpress

For user registration/login and profile, I use the plugin [Ultimate Member](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/)

Now I require only the admins to have user-creation abilities in the front-end. Do wordpress have such a plugin?

Comment: Try this one - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend.

Comment: Not looking that great

Comment: check this one https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/user-role-editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Ultimate Member plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/) + [ACF Frontend display plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-frontend-display/) + [Forms Actions plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/forms-actions/) to show the form in frontend.

Works beautifully!